# Which JavaScript library would you suggest in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I am developing an ASP.NET web application, and now I want to use some charts for my application. I know there are many JavaScript libraries like jQuery, [YUI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_UI_Library) and so on.

What would be best suited for ASP.NET?

Comment: Are you looking for a library that will generate charts or a JavaScript framework?

Comment: Any library or framework

Comment: "JQuery" Microsoft use it on there own sites too. And yes if you want choice there are YUI, Prototype, DOJO in line.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In ASP.NET MVC, Microsoft has actually chosen to include jQuery by default, so I'd say that's one library that MS endorse themselves. I currently use it in almost all of my .NET projects. Visual Studio 2010 will support full intellisense for all of its helper functions. It's also immensely popular right now. I'd say jQuery =)

Answer (score 2):

jQuery if you are looking for transitions with pictures, sliders and all.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference(/partiality) on javascript frameworks just for ASP.NET. I would go for anyone that is easy to learn and work with.

My personal experience : JQuery and for charts I would go for GCharts.

Answer (score 1):

TO generate graphs and charts you might like to look at http://code.google.com/apis/chart/

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery): the best JavaScript library I had ever used.

Remember: JavaScript does not have any dependency with any web framework.
All you need is your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

For ASP.NET, use the Microsoft chart controls: [Scott Guthrie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott_Guthrie)'s blog entry "[New ASP.NET Charting Control: <asp:chart runat="server"/>](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx)".